# Cannot use _source with pagination in Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am facing multiple weird problems when trying to use `_source` in a query with pagination.

If I use `stream` API then the `sourceFilter` is totally discarded. So this query will not generate `_source` json attribute in the query:

```java
SourceFilter sourceFilter = new FetchSourceFilter(new String[]{"emails.sha256"}, null);
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(query)
    .withSourceFilter(sourceFilter)
    .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, pageSize))
    .build();
elasticsearchTemplate.stream(searchQuery, clazz)
```

On the other hand, if I change the `stream` method by `queryForPage`

```java
elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, clazz)
```

The Elasticsearch query is properly generating the `_source` json attribute, but then I face issues with the pagination when the `from` attribute gets quite bigger. The error I get is:

```
{
    "type": "query_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10002]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting."
}
```

I cannot modify `max_result_window` because it will always be big (I have billions of documents).

I also tested the `startScroll` that should resolve the pagination problem but I got a weird `NoSuchMethodError`

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.startScroll(JLorg/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/SearchQuery;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ScrolledPage;
```

I am using Spring Data Elasticsearch `3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and Elasticsearch `6.5.4`

Any idea about how I can paginate a query but limiting the response data using `_source`?

Comment: which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch are you using? I just quickly checked the source code of the actual 3.2.0 and there the sourceFilter is used.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I am using Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and Elasticsearch 6.5.4. Just updated the question with this info

Comment: Can you see if this is solved with 3.2.0.GA (which uses Elasticsearch 6.8.1)?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I tested it with `3.2.0.RELEASE` and faced same issue. Do you know if it is similar to `GA` version?

Comment: yes; can you file an issue in [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAES/issues/)? Btw, I would suggest to switch to using the ElasticsearchRestClient, the ElasticsearchTemplate client is deprecated in the current master branch and will be removed when we support Elasticsearch 8 (because Elasticsearch's TransportClient will be removed then)

Comment: @P.J.Meisch, alright. Thanks a lot for taking the time. I'll test again everything with `ElasticsearchRestClient`.